# PHP Unable to login with session_regenerate_id(true)

Tags: php, session

I have a simple php/mysql webapp I wrote for tracking phone calls, that I'm suddenly having a problem with in the production environment when I added a session_regenerate_id(true) on the index page.  I added this because prior, on logout and log back in I noticed it was retaining the same session_id and I wanted to prevent session hijacking.

On index.php I have:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']!='POST') {
    session_unset();
    session_destroy(); 
    } else { 
    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id(true);
 }
```

I have the request_method check because the index page posts back to itself to validate login attempts.

I have a header file which is included in every page (except index.php) that contains:

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }
    if(isset($_SESSION['SESSION_ID'])){
        $login = true;
    }else{
        session_destroy();
        $url = 'index.php';
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">'; 
        exit;
    }
    if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 3600)) {
    // last request was more than 60 minutes ago
    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
       $url = 'index.php?result=TimedOut';
       echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">'; 
       exit;
}
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
include_once("include/config.inc");
?>
```

Lastly on the logout.php page I have the following:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }
    if(isset($_SESSION['SESSION_ID'])){
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        session_write_close();
        setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/');
        session_regenerate_id(true);
        $url = 'index.php';
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">'; 
    }else{
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        session_write_close();
        setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/');
        session_regenerate_id(true);
        $url = 'index.php';
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">'; 
    }
?>
```

The identical session variables in the else statement is there to handle an edge case of someone hitting logout.php if they don't have a session started, preventing display of a blank page.

As is displayed above, I cannot log into the webapp, it simply kicks my back to the index page however I can see a session file being created in the /tmp directory of the server, which contains the session_id and other session variables I set.

```
UID|s:5:"jack";USER_ROLE|s:1:"2";SESSION_ID|s:32:"fd1d38794eb6c3f6a952d89bda67fd9b";
```

If I comment out the session_regenerate_id(true) in index.php I can login, but the session id never changes, even after a logout.  To make this even strange, the code works as is in my sandbox, which which is the exact same code.  To validate this I put the production and sandbox code on the master branch and verified I was looking at the same git commit.  Further, the virtual host between production and dev sandbox is setup the same.

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>
DocumentRoot /www/htdocs/dev.domain.com
ServerName dev.domain.com
ServerAlias dev.domain.com
ErrorLog /www/logs/dev.domain.com-error_log
CustomLog /www/logs/dev.domain.com-access_log common
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>
DocumentRoot /www/htdocs/calllog
ServerName calllog.domain.com
ServerAlias calllog.domain.com
ErrorLog /www/logs/calllog.domain.com-error_log
CustomLog /www/logs/calllog.domain.com-access_log common
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm kind of at a loss here.  Anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did find out what the exact root cause was.  I resolved the issue by moving the POST into a separate authenticate.php page rather than trying to handle everything in the index page as I originally described.